# Most efficient way of storing database structure

Tags: android

Currently building an app that will have a large, complicated database with many tables. The structure of this database is likely to change at future stages. Instead of hard-coding the structure (and thus making it annoying to come back later and change it) - is there a more efficient way of recording the database structure in android? Ideally I'd like to be able to store the structure in an XML file or something, and then create a function that reads the XML and adapts the database accordingly. Is this a common requirement? If so, what is the standard method?

Answer (score 0):

http://simple.sourceforge.net/

You can use Simple XML to serialize/deserialize objects to and from XML. It will nicelly handle schema changes of your DTOs. And then your serialized xml String's can be stored as a file or as part of a simpler database structure which is what I normally do. In this way the complex and changing parts of your structure can be in xml-mapped-to-dto's and they will reside in the same logical place where you will normally use inside the records of your database.

For the database you can use http://h2database.com/

Answer (score 0):

I use [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) that is very easy to use.

You should try even if it is not a XML file.

First you create new Java Project (eclipse for example) with a simple class :

---

### MAIN CLASS

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Schema schema = new Schema(1, "com.example.yourpackage");
    addEverything(schema);
    new DaoGenerator().generateAll(schema, "../your_android_project_directory/src-gen-dao");
}


private static void addEverything(Schema schema) {
    Entity product = ProductDescriptor.describe(schema);
    Entity module = ModuleDescriptor.describe(schema);
    Entity lienModuleProduit = LinkModuleProductDescriptor.describe(schema, product, module);
}
```

---

### TABLE CLASS

---

```
public class ProductDescriptor {

public static Entity describe(Schema schema) {
    Entity product = schema.addEntity("Product");
    produit.setTableName("product_prd");
    produit.addLongProperty("productId").columnName("PRD_ID").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    produit.addStringProperty("label").columnName("PRD_LBL");
    produit.addFloatProperty("price").columnName("prd_price");
    return product;
}
```

}

---

### TABLE LINK CLASS

---

```
public class LinkModuleProductDescriptor {

public static Entity describe(Schema schema, Entity product, Entity module) {
    Entity linkModuleProduct = schema.addEntity("LinkModuleProduct");
    linkModuleProduct.setTableName("lnk_mod_prd");
    linkModuleProduct.addLongProperty("idLinkModPrd").columnName("LNK_ID").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    Property productId = linkModuleProduct.addLongProperty("productId").notNull().columnName("PRD_ID")
            .getProperty();
    lienModuleProduct.addToOne(product, productId);
    Property moduleId = linkModuleProduct.addLongProperty("moduleId").notNull().columnName("MOD_ID")
            .getProperty();
    linkModuleProduct.addToOne(module, moduleId);
    linkModuleProduct.addIntProperty("moduleVoieNum").columnName("MODULE_VOIE_NUM");
    return linkModuleProduct;
}
```

}

---

### SQL QUERY to ease the writing of your "table class"

---

```
 select data_type from ( 
     SELECT CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('int')      THEN 'addIntProperty ' 
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('smallint') THEN 'addShortProperty ' 
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('bigint')   THEN 'addLongProperty ' 
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('tinyint')  THEN 'addBooleanProperty' 
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('varchar', 'char', 'text', 'longtext') THEN 'addStringProperty ' 
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('date', 'time', 'datetime', 'timestamp') THEN 'addDateProperty ' 
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('decimal') THEN 'addFloatProperty '
                 WHEN DATA_TYPE IN ('blob', 'longblob', 'smallblob') THEN 'addByteProperty ' 
                 ELSE 'probleme' END AS data_type 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME' 
 ) table_temp;
```

You add **src-gen-dao** as a source folder in your Android project.

Then you use greendao. A really nice library.

---

### In your Android project

---

```
    private static void truncateAllTable(final Context context) {
    DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context, DatabaseConstants.DATABASE_NAME, null);
    DaoMaster.dropAllTables(helper.getWritableDatabase(), true);
    DaoMaster.createAllTables(helper.getWritableDatabase(), true);
    helper.close();
}
```

I let you look how to [write queries](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/).